# expo-camera: Error: Permissions module is null

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-camera

I have an error in console after to install expo-camera.

1. expo install expo-camera
2. add permission in android manifest
3. add module expo camera in maven

allprojects {
repositories {

```
    // * Your other repositories here *

    // * Add a new maven block after other repositories / blocks *
    maven {
        // expo-camera bundles a custom com.google.android:cameraview
        url "$rootDir/../node_modules/expo-camera/android/maven"
    }
}
```

}

4. start the protect
5. click on the button to show camera ... error in log

   Error: Permissions module is null.

Permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

update 1 :
I test with this code example to check my permission
https://reactnative.dev/docs/permissionsandroid
my example function

```
 // state local
 const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);
 // function
 const requestCameraPermission = async () => {
        console.log('requestCameraPermission')
        try {
            const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
                PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA,
                {
                    title: "Cool Photo App Camera Permission",
                    message:
                        "Cool Photo App needs access to your camera " +
                        "so you can take awesome pictures.",
                    buttonNeutral: "Ask Me Later",
                    buttonNegative: "Cancel",
                    buttonPositive: "OK"
                }
            );
            if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
                setHasPermission(true)
                console.log("You can use the camera");
            } else {
                console.log("Camera permission denied");
                setHasPermission(false)
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.warn(err);
        }
    };

   // result of requestCameraPermission : You can use the camera
  //  Error  : Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolan expo.modules.interfaces.permission.Permission.hasGrantedPermissions(java.lang.string[]) on a null object reference
```

I make something wrong ?
thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you did just these steps, you have to do more things to make it works on Android device.

[Github page](https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/master/packages/expo-camera#configure-for-android) says:

> Adjust the android/build.gradle to add a new maven block after all other repositories as described below:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {

        // * Your other repositories here *

        // * Add a new maven block after other repositories / blocks *
        maven {
            // expo-camera bundles a custom com.google.android:cameraview
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/expo-camera/android/maven"
        }
    }
}
```

But before do that, you should:

> For bare React Native projects, you must ensure that you have installed and configured the react-native-unimodules package before continuing.

Comment: I had install "react-native-unimodules": "^0.13.3",
and for expo in maven , i add in last but same error

I have in my project expo-barcode-scanner and it's work no problem. 
But expo-camera use the same permission , so i don't undertand.

Comment: @roplopfan I tried locally and it worked... sorry to not be more helpful =(

Comment: maybe i need to clean my project ? i updated my post

Comment: @roplopfan You could try `npm cache clean --force`

Comment: same problem... I use in my phone an android api 24. + firebase.   Maybe it's the problem.
I have this error if i would start my  phone the component camera 
-> Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolan expo.modules.interfaces.permission.Permission.hasGrantedPermissions(java.lang.string[]) on a null object reference

Comment: I can correct the prob.  The prob concern only the react-native-unimodules.
I update the last version and it's work.
The version at the moment: "react-native-unimodules": "^0.14.6",

thanks you for help @Giovanni Esposito

Comment: @roplopfan I'm very happy you solved. Have a nice coding =)